# i deployed a mev slipage bot contract on remix using SepoliaETH however after creation, transfer funds to contract, start, withdraw i got back 0?

Tags: transactions

[image]

here is a screenshot on etherscan of the transactions and after closer inspection i saw that the end traansfer was to this Internal transfer address ????0x1C0801522B7Acef451E388bF3BD9aa9Cb02dB9b2 ???  1.1 ETH
0x9dF3BB...3Bb70423 (contract i deployed remix)

can anyone tell me how this "internal transfer"         @ address
0x1C0801522B7Acef451E388bF3BD9aa9Cb02dB9b2

turned out to be the return address and not the contract address ??? how and where in the solidity code do they write it to make it do such?????

WOW FACINATING TRICKY SCAMMERS!!!!
PS. I tried my best t describe this situation Pleases forgive me for the confusion as I'm learning and have a lot to still learn =}

Comment: It is impossible to make an analysis without the contract source code. If you deployed a contract you have seen on some YT video where all the comments were making tons of money then it is likely you have been scammed.